# brownie deploy using script error

Tags: solidity, contract-development, python, brownie

PS C:\Users\Rakshit_Kumar_Singh\Desktop\brownie-learn> brownie run .\scripts\deploy_testnet.py
Brownie v1.20.0 - Python development framework for Ethereum

File "C:\Users\Rakshit_Kumar_Singh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\brownie_cli_*main*_.py", line 62, in main
importlib.import_module(f"brownie.*cli.{cmd}").main()
File "C:\Users\Rakshit_Kumar_Singh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\brownie_cli\run.py", line 36, in main
args = docopt(**doc**, more_magic=True)
File "C:\Users\Rakshit_Kumar_Singh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\brownie\utils\docopt.py", line 809, in docopt
assert instr.opname.startswith("CALL*")
AssertionError:

Comment: This seems to be related to docopt. See this Brownie issue: https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie/pull/1694